# how can i use function from another class?

Tags: java, javafx

tying to set my project up so that just one controller handles the navigation and that i can just call the function for navigating to another page in a sperate controller and atach that function to a button.

this is the controller i have for navigation

```
package system.test.librarysystem;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class sceneController {

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;

    public void switchToLogin(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml")));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public void switchToBook(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Book.fxml")));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }


    public void switchToDVD(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("DVD.fxml")));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

at the moment im trying to get it to work with this login controller

```
package system.test.librarysystem;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private Label loginLabel;
    @FXML
    private TextField usernameEntry;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordEntry;


    public void loginButtonAction(ActionEvent e) {
        if (usernameEntry.getText().isBlank() == false && passwordEntry.getText().isBlank() == false) {
            //loginLabel.setText("login successful");
            validateLogin();
        } else {
            loginLabel.setText("Please enter username and password");
        }
    }

    public void validateLogin() {
        DatabaseConnection connectNow = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connectDB = connectNow.getConnection();

        String verifyLogin = "SELECT count(1) FROM users WHERE username = '" + usernameEntry.getText() +  "' AND password = '" + passwordEntry.getText() + "'";

        try {

            Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
            ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery(verifyLogin);

            while(queryResult.next()) {
                if (queryResult.getInt(1) ==1 ) {
                    //loginLabel.setText("Welcome");
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Book.FXML"));
                    sceneController sceneController = loader.getController();
                    ActionEvent actionEvent = new ActionEvent();
                    sceneController.switchToBook(actionEvent);

                } else {
                    loginLabel.setText("Invalid login");
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

how can i get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You would need your `LoginController` to have a reference to the instance of `SceneController` *that was created when the corresponding FXML was loaded*. You could in theory do this by passing a reference to that instance to the `LoginController` when you load `Login.fxml` in the `switchToLogin()` method.

Briefly, this would look like:

```
public void switchToLogin(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml")));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    LoginController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setSceneController(this);
    stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

and in the `LoginController`:

```
public class LoginController {

    private SceneController sceneController ;

    public void setSceneController(SceneController sceneController){
        this.sceneController = sceneController;
    }

    // ...

                if (queryResult.getInt(1) ==1 ) {
                    
                    sceneController.switchToBook(null);

                }

    // ...

}
```

However, it's not really good practice to have controllers having dependencies on each other. A better approach is to use a MVC design. In a MVC design, the controller should only update the model. Typically, a view would observe the model and update its controls based on changes in the model data. The JavaFX FXML design is really more of a MVP design, where the "Presenter" collaborates more closely with the view (the FXML). However, the presenter/controller should only update the UI controls for which it is directly responsible; it should not update other UI controls or communicate with other controllers. For example, your login controller is trying to communicate with the scene controller, and your scene controller is trying to modify the scene (which I am fairly sure is not defined in the corresponding FXML).

Instead of communicating between controllers, you should update and observe a model, decoupling all controllers from each other.

Here is a very quick example. This code is also posted [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/james-d/bae73788a9b881cf9358cbf2d842f554).

The model will store and expose a `User` and the current `BrowseState` (which is basically just "is the user browsing DVDs or Books"). For this we have a very simple `record`:

`User.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.library;

public record User(String username) {}
```

and enum:

`BrowseState.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.library;

public enum BrowseState { BOOK, DVD }
```

And then the model is:

`Model.java`

```
package org.jamesd.examples.library;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class Model {
    private final ObjectProperty<User> user = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);

    public User getUser() {
        return user.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<User> userProperty() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user.set(user);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<BrowseState> browseState = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(BrowseState.BOOK);

    public BrowseState getBrowseState() {
        return browseState.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<BrowseState> browseStateProperty() {
        return browseState;
    }

    public void setBrowseState(BrowseState browseState) {
        this.browseState.set(browseState);
    }

    public void logout() {
        setUser(null);
    }
}
```

The idea, common to all MVC-type designs, is that the controllers can update the model and any interested actors can observe the properties in the model if they need to update the UI as a result of values changing.

Here is the `Login.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
          hgap="5" vgap="5"
          alignment="CENTER"
          fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.library.LoginController">

    <Label fx:id="loginLabel" text="Please enter user name and password"
           GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>
    <Label text="Username:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
    <Label text="Password:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>

    <TextField fx:id="usernameEntry" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
    <PasswordField fx:id="passwordEntry" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
            promptText="Password is 'secret'">
            <tooltip>
                <Tooltip text="Password is 'secret'"/>
            </tooltip>
    </PasswordField>

    <HBox alignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
        <Button text="Login" onAction="#loginButtonAction" />
    </HBox>

</GridPane>
```

and its controller

`LoginController.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.library;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class LoginController {

    private final Model model;
    @FXML
    private Label loginLabel;
    @FXML
    private TextField usernameEntry;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordEntry;

    public LoginController(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }


    public void loginButtonAction() {
        String username = usernameEntry.getText();
        String password = passwordEntry.getText();
        if (username.isBlank() || password.isBlank()) {
            loginLabel.setText("Please enter username and password");
        } else {
            if (validateLogin(username, password)) {
                model.setUser(new User(username));
            } else {
                loginLabel.setText("Invalid username and/or password");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean validateLogin(String username, String password) {
        // dummy implementation
        return "secret".equals(password);
    }

}
```

Note this controller does not have a no-arg constructor, which we will deal with later.

More importantly, note that it does not attempt to change the view when the user logs in. All it does is update the model with the new user.

Here is a `Book.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      spacing="20"
      alignment="CENTER"
      fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.library.BookController">
    <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="20"/></padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeLabel"/>
    <Label text="Please browse our books..."/>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="Switch to DVDs" onAction="#switchToDvds"/>
        <Button text="Logout" onAction="#logout"/>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

and its controller:

`BookController.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.library;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class BookController {

    private final Model model;
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeLabel;

    public BookController(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        welcomeLabel.textProperty().bind(
                model.userProperty()
                        .map( u -> String.format("Welcome %s", u.username()))
                        .orElse("Welcome")
        );
    }

    public void switchToDvds() {
        model.setBrowseState(BrowseState.DVD);
    }

    public void logout(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        model.logout();
    }
}
```

As with the `LoginController`, note there is no no-arg constructor, and note it doesn't try to change any UI elements except the ones for which it is directly responsible (the ones defined in `Book.fxml`). It just calls methods on the model.

The DVD, for demo purposes, is basically identical:

Dvd.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      spacing="20"
      alignment="CENTER"
      fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.library.DvdController">
    <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="20"/></padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeLabel"/>
    <Label text="Please browse our DVDs..."/>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="Switch to Books" onAction="#switchToBooks"/>
        <Button text="Logout" onAction="#logout"/>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

`DvdController.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.library;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class DvdController {

    private final Model model;
    @FXML private Label welcomeLabel;

    public DvdController(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        welcomeLabel.textProperty().bind(
                model.userProperty()
                        .map( u -> String.format("Welcome %s", u.username()))
                        .orElse("Welcome")
        );
    }
    public void switchToBooks() {
        model.setBrowseState(BrowseState.BOOK);
    }

    public void logout() {
        model.logout();
    }
}
```

Now all we need to do is assemble the application. The application class should instantiate the model and scene and tie everything together. I will use one additional class: a `ViewManager` class. The responsibility of this class is to observe the model properties and expose a property with the current view that should appear in the scene. This avoids the need for the model (which should just represent data) from having to be aware of any UI details (such as FXML files, scene roots, etc.).

This also uses a controller factory, which is a function the `FXMLLoader` can use to create controller objects from their classes. This uses a little reflection to check if the controller class defines a constructor taking a single parameter of type `Model`: if so, it uses that constructor. (Otherwise it just uses the default constructor.)

`ViewManager.java`.

```
package org.jamesd.examples.library;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.net.URL;

public class ViewManager {

    private final Model model ;

    private final Callback<Class<?>, Object> controllerFactory ;

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Parent> currentView = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

    public Parent getCurrentView() {
        return currentView.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Parent> currentViewProperty() {
        return currentView.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public ViewManager(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        controllerFactory = type -> {
            try {
                for (Constructor<?> c : type.getConstructors()) {
                    if (c.getParameterCount() == 1 && c.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(Model.class)) {
                        return c.newInstance(model);
                    }
                }
                return type.getConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e instanceof RuntimeException re ? re : new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };

        ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> updateView();
        model.userProperty().addListener(listener);
        model.browseStateProperty().addListener(listener);
        updateView();
    }

    private void updateView() {
        try {
            URL resource;
            if (model.getUser() == null) {
                resource = LoginController.class.getResource("Login.fxml");
            } else {
                resource = switch(model.getBrowseState()) {
                    case DVD -> DvdController.class.getResource("Dvd.fxml");
                    case BOOK -> BookController.class.getResource("Book.fxml");
                };
            }
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
            loader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
            currentView.set(loader.load());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Now the application class just creates the model, view manager, and scene, and binds the scene's root to the current view in the view manager:

`HelloApplication.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.library;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Model model = new Model();
        ViewManager viewManager = new ViewManager(model);
        Scene scene = new Scene(viewManager.getCurrentView(), 800, 500);
        scene.rootProperty().bind(viewManager.currentViewProperty());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: the most longest answer ever seen

Comment: I mean your contribution deserves the appreciation.  As you've spent 30 minutes. So my comment is nothing more than respect